# How to address ImageUrl using " serverlocation + table value " in asp tag in c# web programming?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:Image ID ="ImageNameLabel" runat ="server" ImageUrl ='<%#Eval("ImageLocation")%>+ <%#Eval("ImageName")%>'/>
```

Please tell me how to add to value in the asp tag.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that using data-bindig?

```
<img src="http://localhost/<%# Eval("FileName") %>" />
```